# Setting an appropriate environment to work

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Here begins the road. I need to configure a working environment manageable and accessible. I've been reading a bit about environment variables. Windows have an easy configuration, as can be easily changed through window panes. In unix is different ...

`export environment_variable = argument` 
eg. export DISPLAY = localhost: 0.0.
The question is: should I declare the environment variables when I install rvm? need to work with ruby, and not have to be writing the `source` myvar each time I start the console.

Same question for node and git.
Obviously I ask because in windows if I had to do, and I have unix doubt.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer to your question is No. During the installation, setup and use of rvm, you will not be setting any environment-specific variables that relate to your application, nor for the rubies/gemsets/gems that rvm will be managing for you.

Once rvm is up and running, and you have installed at least one version of ruby (managed by rvm), there are a few options available to you for conveniently managing your environment variables.

a) You can use your unix shell config files (.bashrc, .bash_profile, etc.) to set env variables, but I don't recommend it. ***This is the equivalent of the Windows scenario you quoted in your question***, but is not the common practice in the ruby-unix community.

b) If you are using Rails, environment-specific configurations can be managed in the source code itself, in environment files. For example, production.rb, development.rb, test.rb. etc.

c) If this is a Ruby codebase (i.e. no Rails) then, you can define your environment variables in an 'initializer' file, which can be invoked at the entry point of your ruby project. I typically put my application-specific variables in a yaml file like below.

In file: `env_vars.yaml`

```
---
:env_var_a: a.b.com    
:env_var_b: 1111    
:env_var_c: foo    
:env_var_d: bar
```

To load these environment variables for use in your codebase,

```
require 'yaml'
env_vars = YAML.load(File.read(file_path('env_vars.yml')))
```

If you prefer to not use YAML, you can save the configs in a text file, and use ruby's native `File` class to access them. I like YAML because it easily creates a hash for me.

Regardless of which option you choose, there is **no way** you will need to type `source` every time you start a session

Comment: First of all, thanks for your detailed reply Changingrainbows. If I understand also, those who declare the varible telling you where going to use the ready to use. Instead of having a place where they are always entered and available for use.
If so, it's a twist that I honestly had not imagined if I say so.

In other words, these variables suggesting that you set so that when you call to rails with source, the load the appropriate environment using preconfigured file.

Thank you very much in advance and be sure that I reread more than once your advice.

Comment: haha. No problem! Hope you find ruby on unix as powerful and efficient as I do. Good luck.